# Change style of tabs in bokeh plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to know if there is a way to change the properties of tabs produced on a bokeh plot. Changes like increasing the text font, changing the tab width and so on. The following is a simple code for producing a plot with two tabs.

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("slider.html")

p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="circle")

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ])

show(tabs)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override the default Bokeh tabs styles like shown below (works for Bokeh v1.1.0).

> Please note that Bokeh CSS library implementation may change in
>   upcoming versions.

The css styles found below will work for v1.1.0 but **are not** backwards compatible with v1.0.4

```
from bokeh.plotting import save, figure
from bokeh.models import Paragraph, Panel, Tabs, Column

template = """
{% block postamble %}
<style>
.bk-root .bk-tab {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 200px;
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}

.bk-root .bk-tabs-header .bk-tab.bk-active{
background-color: yellow;
color: blue;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
}

.bk-root .bk-tabs-header .bk-tab:hover{
background-color: yellow
}

</style>
{% endblock %}
"""

p = Paragraph(text = "Another tab", width = 600)

plot = figure()
plot.line(x = [1, 2], y = [3, 4])
tabs = [Panel(title = 'Tab1', child = plot)]
tabs.append(Panel(title = 'Tab2', child = p))

save(Column(Tabs(tabs = tabs, width = 600)), template = template)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I would only add: The general answer is "style the CSS" but please note that the DOM structure/CSS is still considered an implementation detail at this point, and may still change over time.

Comment: This works, but wonder if there is a way of doing this in the Theme.yaml file